# How to extract coordinates from contour lines in python and store them in new x and y variables?

Tags: python, extract, contour

I am facing a problem in extracting coordinates from a contour plot. I first plotted contour line in python. Then I want to extract only the x,y coordinates along the contour line and store them in x and y variables to use them in the next operation. I saw a code to extract the coordinates along the contour in the forum but that does not give me points to store in separate x and y variable so that I can use them in the next operation.

Please help me if there is an easy python code possible for this operation. I am not expert in python.

I have tried a link from the forum but that does not give me coordinates like x y it comes with bracketed x and y. I cannot write the code here as it shows some error in this editing window.

```
def get_contour_verts(cp):
    contours=[]
    for cc in cp.collections:
        paths=[]
        for pp in cc.get_paths():
            xy=[]
            for vv in pp.iter_segments():
                xy.append(vv[0])
            paths.append(np.vstack(xy))
        contours.append(paths)
    return contours

contours=get_contour_verts(cp)
      for ip,path in enumerate(contours):
        for i,item in enumerate(path):

           print(path[i])
```

Using this code I get output path[i] containing x and y within brackets together. I want to save the output x and y coordinates as an array.
The output data looks like,

[[-0.0018     -0.02222131]]

But I want them as x=-0.0018    y= -0.02222131
Thanks,

I just tried with
      for ip,path in enumerate(contours):
        for i,item in enumerate(path):
            print(item[i][0],item[i][1])

But it is not giving me a list of x and y values but showing error "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1"

Comment: what module do you use? What code do you use? What contour do you mean? What link from forum do you mean? What error do you get when you put code?

Comment: put code in question or it will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: Hello, I have now added the code which I used to extracting points from contour. Please see if you can help me to get the output points as array to use them in the next processing.

Comment: first show your data. I don't know what you have and I can't test code without data. Second "brackets" means array so probably you already have coordinates as array. I don't know where and how you try to save it but probalby you do it in wrong way and it converts array to string with brackets but you should write `x` and `y` separatelly or format data manually.

Comment: did you try simply `path[i][0]` and `path[i][0]` to get it separatelly - `print(path[i][0],  path[i][0])` or `print(item[0], item[1])` or format it manually before you print it.

Comment: if `path[i]` give `[[-0.0018 -0.02222131]]` then `x = path[i][0][0]` and `y = path[i][0][1]`

Comment: you get new error because you shouldn't use `i` with `item` - `print(item[0], item[1])` . You can use `i` only with `path` - `print(path[i][0][0], path[i][0][1])` . `path[i]` and `item` are the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

If `path[i]` gives `[[-0.0018 -0.02222131]]` then

```
 x = path[i][0][0]
 y = path[i][0][1]
```

Comment: I just used your suggestion but I am getting only one row of x and y values. I should get list of coordinates.

Comment: then create list for data and `append()` values.